# Input adopter stage not rending properly in screen

Tags: java, libgdx

I have an abstract class which implements the [screen](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) interface. despite that stage instance properly added with in render method, screen stay frozen and thus [stage](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java) instance wont properly react by time pass.

Here are the code snippets of the abstract class and calling point of stage instance with in `render()`  method.

```
public abstract class Scene<R extends InputProcessor> implements Screen {
    protected Scene(Stage stage, R r) {
        this.r = r;
        this.stage = stage;
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(r);
        ...
       
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 0);
        context().trigger(r);
        stage.act(delta);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }


    ...

    private final Stage stage;
}
```

Yet stage instance is not null and instantiate properly but it does not change the frame with delta lifecycle.

Full description added